# How to Add % symbol in html input type text

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am trying to append percent symbol to a number in textbox  using `pipe.Transform()` method.

```
<Input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">

let test=12345;
this.value=this.percentPipe.transform(test,'1.0-3');
```

Can I use this method to just add `%` symbol  without transforming it?

Comment: Please provide the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **angular material**, then you can simply add Suffix in the input.

Example:

```
 <form class="example-form"> 
   <md-input-container class="example-full-width"> 
         <input type="number" mdInput>
         <span mdSuffix *ngIf="showPercentSymbol">%</span>
     </md-input-container>
 </form>
```

Link to the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

**EDIT 2020**:
`mdSuffix` has been replaced with `matSuffix` - see below:

```
 <form class="example-form"> 
   <md-input-container class="example-full-width"> 
         <input type="number" mdInput>
         <span matSuffix *ngIf="showPercentSymbol">%</span>
     </md-input-container>
 </form>
```

Link to latest docs: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix--suffix

Comment: Ok, but this will appear everytime.if I want it on special case, i have to write something in component.this won't work right?

Comment: You can add a condition on the suffix span. See the updated answer.