# How to suffix unit in a textbox html Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to create a textbox in angular which should look like below
[image]
When I start inputting text the unit should move to the right as shown below.
[image]
When I try to access the value in .ts file I only want the numeric value.

Comment: There is a suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411254/how-to-add-symbol-in-html-input-type-text

Comment: @DeborahK its using Material. But I dont want it in angular material. Any leads on custom implementation?